# How to get the model name from /proc/cpuinfo in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am working in C and trying to get specific information from `/proc` files.
I know in linux when I do the following I get the model name.

```
cd /proc
cat cpuinfo | grep 'model name'
```

but if I'm trying to do this in C it results in a `core dumped`

```
thisfile = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' ", "r");
```

How can I get the model name when opening a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fopen("/proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' ", "r");` will return a NULL pointer because the file `/proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'` certainly doesn't not exist

*fopen* allows to open a file, not to execute commands

Use *popen* :

```
FILE * fp = popen("grep 'model name'  /proc/cpuinfo", "r");

if (fp != NULL) {
  ...read in 
  pclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and help!